# guestbook ajax php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Have been trying to make a guestbook with jquery, ajax and php, I have been able to reed and print out everything inside the database but for some reason I cant save what I write in the database and then print it out as a post in the guestbook, if someone could see what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it! (for now I only try to get the username inside the database)

this is the jquery:

```
$("#newPost").bind('click', function(){
    var userName = $('#userName').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "server.php?action=newPost",
        type: "POST",
        data: {userName: userName},
        success: function(data){
            if(data == "true"){
                alert(data);
                $('#posts').prepend('<td>'+userName+'</td>');
                $('#userName').val('');
            }
            else{
                alert('Something went wrong while trying to save!');
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, error){
            alert('Could not connect to server!');          
        }

        });
    });
```

this is the server.php file:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'my_database');

if(isset($GET_['action']) && $GET_['action'] == 'newPost'){
    $userName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, POST_['userName']);
    if(mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO message (name) VALUES ('$userName')")){
        echo "true";
    }
    else{
        echo "false";
    }

}
```

and tis is the html form:

```
<form action="#"> 
    <p>Name:</p>
    <textarea type="text" class="field" id="userName" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea><br/><br/>
    <p>Meddelande:</p>
    <textarea type="text" class="field" id="message" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea><br/><br/>
    <input value="Send" class="button" type="button" id="newPost"></input><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: Echo the userName, there's nothing in it. It should also have a 'name'

Comment: `url: "server.php?action=newPost",` are you sure this is the right path to the file you're trying to access? `server.php` may be in a different location.

Comment: it is in the same folder as all the other files...

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `$GET_` and `POST_` with `$_GET` and `$_POST`

Also your field names are empty, add `name="userName"` and `name="message"` to your textarea HTML tags

Comment: thanks for that but I still get the message Could not connect to server each time???

Comment: if i only fill out the name field I get the Something went wrong while trying to save! pop up instead?

Comment: Try referencing to this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6960586/488074) or any other AJAX request for constructing your request. I don't like this piece "data: {userName: userName}", otherwise print out the messages coming from (xhr, error)

Comment: For debugging Javascipt I would recommend use the command "console.log(xhr);", then open a console with Firebug or something. Then you can debug that object very easily.

Comment: now I can see that the result of data returns false? know why?

Comment: Try debugging all these objects; `(xhr, error, msg){` also I would consider rewriting your AJAX call, look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the name in your textarea. So $userName is empty.